# Прикрепить картинку поверх страницы js

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Собственно, есть расширение, оно перенапрявляет с любой страницы на страницу с картинкой. Мне нужно чтобы она просто прикреплялась поверх страницы. Я пытался прикреплять к элементам, менять размер, но она лепилась как понятно либо вниз, либо висела на бэкграунде. Как можно прикрепить ее поверх страницы?

Answer (score 1):

В самый верх страницы добавьте блок div с нужным вам изображением и поработайте со стилями для корректного отображения. Если у вас на сайте что-то вроде ссылки на картинку и она должна при определённом действии появиться - используйте pop up, благо инфы по ним просто уйма в интеренете!